# How to debug Safari CPU utilization and spinning beach ball?

Tags: macos, safari, performance

I have been plagued by performance problems in my late 2010 MacBook Air for several months now. Most of it seems centred around Safari. I regularly get very high fan speeds (loud to the point of very annoying), very warm laptop, high load average, and spinning BBOD (beach ball of death), especially on Safari.

I consistently have a single window, 8-10 tabs, none of them heavy dynamic apps (Gmail and Calendar running in Chrome).

I regularly have CPU spikes from Safari and WebContent (and at times soagent). They rarely last very long, but when they do, I see the BBOD and Safari is completely unusable, then the rest of the laptop slows down to a crawl.

I have taken a spindump of Safari - it takes a **very** long time - but I do not actually know how to interpret it to see where it is stuck.

I have almost no extensions installed. Just 1Password, AdBlock and ClickToPlugin (which was installed specifically to prevent Flash and others from bogging it down).

What can I do to narrow down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adblock runs against every frame in the page. This is probably not all of your problem, but it is significant, at least it was for me. Switch to [ublock](https://www.ublock.org) and you should see a difference. Read the advanced docs and graduate to the the firewall style usage of this tool, and you will be very pleased.

Comment: Do you know how to interpret a spindump. Had the same behaviour yesterday - some network problem to a particular site, and Safari started chewing CPU so I took a spindump - but I do not know how to interpret it to narrow down what it is spinning on.

Comment: Well, I went to uBlock, as suggested. It helped a bit, so upvote, but I still had to kill Safari because of permanent spinning beach ball just five mins ago. Sigh. Wish I knew how to interpret the spindump so I could know what is killing it.

Comment: uBlock/µBlock [doesn’t seem to be devolped for Safari anymore](https://github.com/chrisaljoudi/uBlock/issues/1544#issuecomment-150397875), and [uBlock Origin never was](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1596). I don’t know about the efficiency of the alleged alternative [Purify](https://www.purify-app.com) (on iOS) or other extensions that support Apple’s newish Content Blocker API.

Comment: It sucks about ublock for Safari. I use adguard for now. I'll  browse the web via psychics before I go back to no adblocking.